# VBA How to create an If to close a file if it was open

Tags: excel, vba

At the end of the macro, I have functions that close the open sheets of the fumulators you fill out. However, sometimes one of them will not be there. Let's say data_wb1 has not been started. When the macro finishes, it shows me error : Required object. here `If Not data_wb1 Is Nothing Then`

```
If Not data_wb2 Is Nothing Then
data_wb2.Close True
Else
End If
If Not data_wb1 Is Nothing Then
data_wb1.Close True
Else
End If
If Not data_wb Is Nothing Then
data_wb.Close True
Else
```

Comment: How did  you declare the variables? They need to be declared as an object type, not say a Variant.

Comment: you are right Rory ! wrong set Variable :) thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that either you don't use `Option Explicit` and never declared the Variable (so VBA implicitly creates it on the fly as Variant), or you declared it as `Variant` instead of `Workbook`.

Now a Variant can be anything, a Number, a Date, an Object. If you don't assign anything to a Variant, it has it's initial value which is `Empty`.

An Object Variable (eg of type Workbook) points to an Object when you use the `Set`-command. Usually, this is called *It gets a reference to it*. When declared, it's initial value is `Nothing` which means it doesn't point to an object.

Now you need to distinguish between `Empty` and `Nothing`. To check for `Nothing`. you need an Object Variable, else you will get the *Object required* runtime error.

In your case:
**(a)** Use Option Explicit (always!)
**(b)** Declare your variables (data_wb, data_wb1, data_wb2) as `Workbook`

```
Dim data_wb as Workbook, data_wb1  as Workbook, data_wb2 as Workbook
```

That should solve your problem

---

Note: You should use Variant only if necessary and in your case I don't think it's necessary). But if you insist in using Variants, you can assign `Nothing` to them.

```
Dim data_wb as Variant, data_wb1 as Variant, data_wb2 as Variant
Set data_wb = Nothing
Set data_wb1 = Nothing
Set data_wb2 = Nothing
```

In that case, they are no longer `Empty` and the VBA runtime understands that you are dealing with Object references and that they currently don't point to anything.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, unfortunately I built a huge macro without option explicit. Now I can see how big a mistake I made.